# Ajax request returns 200 OK, but an error event is fired instead of success

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I have implemented an Ajax request on my website, and I am calling the endpoint from a webpage. It always returns **200 OK**, but **jQuery** executes the error event.
I tried a lot of things, but I could not figure out the problem. I am adding my code below:

#### jQuery Code

```
var row = "1";
var json = "{'TwitterId':'" + row + "'}";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Jqueryoperation.aspx?Operation=DeleteRow',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: json,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: AjaxSucceeded,
    error: AjaxFailed
});
function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
    alert("hello");
    alert(result.d);
}
function AjaxFailed(result) {
    alert("hello1");
    alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
}
```

#### C# code for `JqueryOpeartion.aspx`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    test();
}
private void test() {
    Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Record Deleted');</script>");
}
```

I need the `("Record deleted")` string after successful deletion. I am able to delete the content, but I am not getting this message. Is this correct or am I doing anything wrong? What is the correct way to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you run the output of JqueryOperation.aspx through a JSON validator and see if it valid JSON

Comment: Like http://jsonlint.com/ . You also have to check the parameters you send. Currently you have not set any parameter name. If the parameter is `TwitterId`, then you have to pass an object to `data`, not a string: `data: {TwitterId: row}`.

Comment: Does the Jqueryoperation.aspx page return (valid) JSON?

Comment: probably your server side code is throwing an exception .. what r u returning in your catch block as the response?

Comment: @Raghav, if the server threw an exception processing the request, then the HTTP return code would be 500.

Comment: I dont understand why you have to use both POST, and GET?besides twitterId should be in double quotes not single,

Comment: @Val: its perfectly OK to have Query String parameters along with POST data.

Comment: I didnt say it wasn't I am just saying why use both and complicate things, simple is better that all :)

Comment: This answer may not be complete. Just now I validated my JSON at `jsonlint.com`, it explicitly says that it is a vaild json, but still "error" event is fired, with `xhr.status` 200. what other reasons can be there?

Comment: Is there no way to get JQuery to actually show its error?

Answer (score 1259, accepted):

[`jQuery.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) attempts to convert the response body based on the specified `dataType` parameter or the `Content-Type` header sent by the server. If the conversion fails (e.g. if the JSON/XML is invalid), the error callback is fired.

---

Your AJAX code contains:

```
dataType: "json"
```

In this case jQuery:

> Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. […]
> The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is
> rejected and a parse error is thrown. […] an empty response is also
> rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead.

Your server-side code returns HTML snippet with `200 OK` status. jQuery was expecting valid JSON and therefore fires the error callback complaining about `parseerror`.

The solution is to remove the `dataType` parameter from your jQuery code and make the server-side code return:

```
Content-Type: application/javascript

alert("Record Deleted");
```

But I would rather suggest returning a JSON response and display the message inside the success callback:

```
Content-Type: application/json

{"message": "Record deleted"}
```

Answer (score 47):

You simply have to remove the **dataType: "json"** in your AJAX call

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Jqueryoperation.aspx?Operation=DeleteRow',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: json,
    dataType: 'json', //**** REMOVE THIS LINE ****//
    cache: false,
    success: AjaxSucceeded,
    error: AjaxFailed
});
```

Answer (score 37):

I've had some good luck with using multiple, space-separated `dataType`s ([jQuery 1.5+](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)). As in:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Jqueryoperation.aspx?Operation=DeleteRow',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: json,
    dataType: 'text json',
    cache: false,
    success: AjaxSucceeded,
    error: AjaxFailed
});
```

Answer (score 24):

This is just for the record since I bumped into this post when looking for a solution to my problem which was similar to the OP's.

In my case my jQuery Ajax request was prevented from succeeding due to [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) in Chrome. All was resolved when I modified my server (Node.js) to do:

```
response.writeHead(200,
          {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:8080"
        });
```

It literally cost me an hour of banging my head against the wall. I am feeling stupid...

Answer (score 16):

I reckon your aspx page doesn't return a JSON object.
Your page should do something like this (page_load)

```
var jSon = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var OutPut = jSon.Serialize(<your object>);

Response.Write(OutPut);
```

Also, try to change your AjaxFailed:

```
function AjaxFailed (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {

}
```

`textStatus` should give you the type of error you're getting.

Answer (score 13):

I have faced this issue with an updated jQuery library. If the service method is not returning anything it means that the return type is `void`.

Then in your Ajax call please mention `dataType='text'`.

It will resolve the problem.

Comment: And also if the service method is returning a simple string java object will expect the dataType as text.

Answer (score 9):

You just have to remove `dataType: 'json'` from your header if your implemented Web service method is void.

In this case, the Ajax call don't expect to have a JSON return datatype.

Answer (score 7):

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9985307/6936747). It's also a similar problem. Working I tried.

Dont remove `dataType: 'JSON',`

**Note: Your response data should be in json format**

Comment: The content mentioned in bold is important response must have a body, thanks for saving time.

Answer (score 5):

Use the following code to ensure the response is in JSON format (PHP version)...

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return_vars);
exit;
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. My problem was my controller was returning a status code instead of JSON. Make sure that your controller returns something like:

```
public JsonResult ActionName(){
   // Your code
   return Json(new { });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another thing that messed things up for me was using `localhost` instead of 127.0.0.1 or vice versa. Apparently, JavaScript can't handle requests from one to the other.

Answer (score 2):

If you always return JSON from the server (no empty responses), `dataType: 'json'` should work and `contentType` is not needed. However make sure the JSON output...

- is valid ([JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/))
- **is serialized** ([JSONMinify](https://www.cleancss.com/json-minify/))

jQuery AJAX will throw a 'parseerror' on valid but unserialized JSON!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It was because my JSON response contains some special characters and the server file was not encoded with UTF-8, so the Ajax call considered that this was not a valid JSON response.

Answer (score -1):

Your script demands a return in JSON data type.

Try this:

```
private string test() {
  JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 return js.Serialize("hello world");
}
```