# jQuery: How to iterate through JSON encoded string (array)

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, foreach, each

I am a jQuery beginner and hope someone can help me with this and also provide me some explanations.

I have an Ajax call that returns a JSON encoded string with two values for each item, an **itemID** and an **itemVal** - **an example looks as follows** (using `console.log`):

**console.log(data) result:**

```
string(225) "[{"itemID":1,"itemVal":"China"},{"itemID":2,"itemVal":"France"},{"itemID":3,"itemVal":"Germany"},{"itemID":4,"itemVal":"Italy"},{"itemID":5,"itemVal":"Poland"},{"itemID":6,"itemVal":"Russia"},{"itemID":7,"itemVal":"USA"},...]"
```

The number of items here varies but if an itemID is listed than there is always a corresponding itemVal.
itemID is a unique integer, itemVal is plain text.

Everything works so far but here comes my problem:
**For each itemID here I have to do something with the corresponding itemVal**, e.g. say just log it to the console or alert it for testing.

I know there are various approaches for this like `jQuery.each, $.each, for, foreach` etc. but since I just started recently I am not sure how I can iterate through this resp. how I can select the single itemIDs from it.

I tried different approaches, incl. `$.parseJSON(data)` which failed and it seems the problem is that my input before being decoded is a **two-dimensional array instead of a one-dimensional one** (I hope I am using the right terms here) which caused them to either return an error or to alert every single character of my string.

**Update - failing example as per the answer below**

```
$.ajax({        
    type: "post",   
    url: "ajax.php",
    cache: "false",
    data: {
        node: 'fetchCountries',
        itemIDs: itemIDs // a list of integers
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var arr = JSON.parse(data);
        $.each($(arr),function(key,value){
           console.log(value.itemVal);
        });
    }
});
```

**Update 2 - My PHP:**

```
case "fetchCountries":
    $intval_itemIDs = array_map("intval", $_POST["itemIDs"]);
    $itemIDs = implode(",", $intval_itemIDs);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT itemID, en FROM Countries WHERE itemID IN(" . $itemIDs . ") ORDER BY itemID");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while($arrCountries = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $countries[] = array("itemID" => $arrCountries["itemID"], "itemVal" => $arrCountries["en"]);
    }
    var_dump(json_encode($countries));
    break;
```

**Expected outcome** (for testing)**:**

```
console.log("China");
console.log("France");
console.log("Germany");
// ...
```

Can someone help me with this ?

Many thanks, 
Tim

Comment: It's an array or it's JSON ("text"). It's not both.

Comment: You are right, sorry. It's the result from an Ajax call that uses a PHP query. On the PHP side it is an array and before I send it back to JS there I use json_encode - you can see how it looks in my post.

Comment: Which PHP version you were using @WhistleBlower

Comment: @Uchiha: I can choose between 5.4, 5.5 and 5.6 and have now set it to 5.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for the help with this.

Since all other approaches made sense to me but still failed I did some more research on this and finally found what was causing this.

The issue was indeed on the PHP side and the **accepted answer on the following post did the trick** - since I added this to my PHP everything else on the JS side is working fine and I don't even need the dataType: "JSON" there:

[dataType: "json" won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985146/datatype-json-wont-work)

**As per this post the solution for my case is the following - kudos to Jovan Perovic:**

```
<?php
//at the very beginning start output buffereing
ob_start();

// do your logic here

// right before outputting the JSON, clear the buffer.
ob_end_clean();

// now print
echo json_encode(array("id" => $realid, "un" => $username, "date" => $date));
?>
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

> You're not parsing a string, you're parsing an already-parsed object

just use it directly

```
var data=[{"itemID":1,"itemVal":"China"},{"itemID":2,"itemVal":"France"},{"itemID":3,"itemVal":"Germany"},{"itemID":4,"itemVal":"Italy"},{"itemID":5,"itemVal":"Poland"},{"itemID":6,"itemVal":"Russia"},{"itemID":7,"itemVal":"USA"}];

    $.each(data,function(key,value){
        console.log(value.itemVal);
    });
```

or/

```
 var arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

    $.each(arr, function (key, value) {
        console.log(value.itemVal);
    });
```

**Update 1:**

I think so your php file like

```
    <?php 
      $array = array( array( 'itemID' => 1, 'itemVal' => 'India'), array( 'itemID' => 2, 'itemVal' => 'usa'), array( 'itemID' => 3, 'itemVal' => 'china'), array( 'itemID' => 4, 'itemVal' => 'uk'));
        echo json_encode($array);
//[{"itemID":1,"itemVal":"India"},{"itemID":2,"itemVal":"usa"},{"itemID":3,"itemVal":"china"},{"itemID":4,"itemVal":"uk"}]
     ?>
```

your script should be

```
  $.getJSON( "your.php", function( data ) {
              console.log(data);
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    console.log(value.itemVal);
                });
            });
```

OR

```
  $.ajax({        
          type: "post",   
          url: "your.php",
          cache: "false",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {
              node: 'fetchCountries',
              itemIDs: youval // a list of integers
          },
          success: function(data){
              console.log(data);
                var arr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
              $.each($(arr),function(key,value){
                 console.log(value.itemVal);
              });
          }
      });
```

OR

```
    $.ajax({        
      type: "post",   
      url: "your.php",
      cache: "false",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
          node: 'fetchCountries',
          itemIDs: youval // a list of integers
      },
      success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
          $.each($(data),function(key,value){
             console.log(value.itemVal);
          });
      }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this as welll ! - Both approaches return a new error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length'"

Comment: use `dataType:'json',` let me know

Comment: Thanks. When I use this then the console logs nothing - it seems then my PHP doesn't return anything.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the delay ! I just added my PHP to the post.

Comment: I seen your php its fine, now you try with my updated scripts above!!

Comment: Thanks so much for all your effort ! I am still getting the same errors or nothing in the console. It seems to me that the problem is dataType: "JSON" as whenever I add this I am not getting anything back from my PHP and otherwise I cannot do anything with the data received as suggested.

Comment: Thanks again - I finally figured out what was causing this and posted it as an answer since this was something different.

Answer (score 1):

You have a JSON string representing an Array, which you are parsing into an actual `Array`.  Then you are looping through the array, pushing each element into a new Array (`arr`).

Perhaps there is some confusion.  Hopefully [this](http://jsbin.com/dukexirero/edit?js,console) will shed some light.

```
// Considering the following JSON string:
var data = '[{"itemID":1,"itemVal":"China"},{"itemID":2,"itemVal":"France"},{"itemID":3,"itemVal":"Germany"},{"itemID":4,"itemVal":"Italy"},{"itemID":5,"itemVal":"Poland"},{"itemID":6,"itemVal":"Russia"},{"itemID":7,"itemVal":"USA"}]';

// You can create an Array from this like so:
var theArray = JSON.parse(data);

// Now you have an array with each item being an `object`
// with an "itemId" and an "itemVal".  You can loop through
// this array and look at each object like so:
theArray.forEach(function (obj) {
    console.log(obj.itemID + ': ' + obj.itemVal);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this - your explanation makes sense but this still returns the same error as in the above answer. In Chrome: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A" - in FF: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Answer (score 1):

WhistleBlower, I have tested your code on my browser. It worked. Why don't you use header("Content-type :application/json"); too. So, you will not have to parse your JSON string.

```
var data = '[{"itemID":1,"itemVal":"China"},{"itemID":2,"itemVal":"France"},{"itemID":3,"itemVal":"Germany"},{"itemID":4,"itemVal":"Italy"},{"itemID":5,"itemVal":"Poland"},{"itemID":6,"itemVal":"Russia"},{"itemID":7,"itemVal":"USA"}]';
var arr = JSON.parse(data);
$.each($(arr),function(key,value){
   console.log(value.itemVal);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this as well ! I did some more research and this might actually be it since all other approaches failed so far. Can you explain where and how I have to apply this ? I have never used it before.

Comment: Take a look at [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31530727/json-encode-not-working-with-get/31530860#31530860) there.

Comment: Do you realy need to make your JS variable arr an jQuery object? You can try this.  $.each(arr, function(key,value){
  console.log(value.itemVal);
 });

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this!

```
$.each($(data),function(key,value){
   console.log(value.itemVal); //place alert if you want instead of console.log
});
```

iterate through the obtained result and get `itemVal` value of each `item`

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/09136p5e/)**

---

**UPDATE**

Add `dataType` option to your `ajax` and return type from `php` should be `json` and I hope you are doing that!

```
$.ajax({        
    type: "POST",   
    url: "ajax.php",
    cache: "false",
    dataType:'json', //Add this
    data: {
        node: 'fetchCountries',
        itemIDs: itemIDs // a list of integers
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var arr = JSON.parse(data);
        $.each($(arr),function(key,value){
           console.log(value.itemVal);
        });
    }
});
```

and return from your `php` should be `echo json_encode(result);`

Comment: Try the demo and let me know!!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply ! It works well with your demo but when testing this with my code it only logs the word "Array".

Comment: Can you post the updated code? and also `console.log(JSON.parse(data))` + try expanding the `Array` in console and see what you get!

Comment: Thanks - just added it to the post. It looks like it still treats my data as a string.

Comment: what you get on `console.log` of `arr`? Post a screen shot if possible!

Comment: Update: I cannot expand the Array in the console and am not getting any errors in Chrome but in FF I get the following, referring to the var line: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Comment: Ok!! Just remove `JSON.parse` and pass the direct `data` object and try!

Comment: console.log(data) logs the word "Array" - console.log(arr) returns the following error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token A"

Comment: Just remove `JSON.parse` and try it on plain `data` as I've shown in my answer!

Comment: I did that already and it logs the word "Array". Maybe the issue is on the PHP side ? Is json_encode the right approach there ?

Comment: Thanks again ! This logs nothing - it looks like this doesn't work with my PHP query.

Comment: @WhistleBlower. The above code should work perhaps if there isnt any problems with your php!

Comment: Thanks again - I finally figured out what was causing this and posted it as an answer since this was something different.