# ajax can not receive JSON from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have issues with receiving a JSON object from PHP. I can alert it and get a  ( I think correct) JSON Object with `dataType: 'text'`, but not use it like `data.message` --> it is "undefined". With `dataType: 'json'`,`'jsonp'` or the ajax call `$.getJSON` it does not work (It does not fire this request).

AJAX

```
$('#login').click(function () {
var name = $('#username').val();
var pass = $('#password').val();
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/weltenbummler/Weltenbummler1/Weltenbummler1/app/login.php?username=" + name + "&password=" + pass,
    dataType: 'text',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (d) {
        alert(d);
        alert(d.message);
    }
});});
```

Alerted JSONs

`{"status":"f","message":"Benutzername und Passwort stimmen nicht ueberein"}` or

`{"status":"t","message":"Erfolgreich eingeloggt!","data":{"id":"1","mail":"abc","password":"123"}}`

I tested the received String on jsonlint.com and it should be valid. I tried to `JSON.parse(data)` , `$.parseJSON(data)` what does not work.
`JSON.stringify(data)` is returning the JSON with slashes (I do not know why).

Postman can read it as well in HTML, text, XML or JSON...

In php I tried to change the header to 
`header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");`
or to force the response as JSON.

connect.php file:

```
<?php
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$user= "root";
$pw="";
$db = "weltenbummler";

//Create connection
$con = new mysqli($host,$user,$pw,$db);


//Check connection
if($con->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " .$con->connect_error);
}?>
```

login.php file:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
require 'connect.php';

$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];

$response = array();
if(empty($username)){
    $response = array(
        "status " => " f",
        "message " => " Gebe einen Benutzernamen ein!"
    );
    die(json_encode($response));
}
if(empty($password)){
    $response = array(
        "status" => "f",
        "message"=> "Gebe ein Passwort ein!"
    );
    die(json_encode($response));
}

$sqlstatement= ("SELECT id,mail,password FROM user WHERE mail = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($con->query($sqlstatement));

if (!$result) {
    $response = array(
        "status" => "f",
        "message" => "Benutzername und Passwort stimmen nicht ueberein"
    );
} else {
    $response = array(
        "status" => "t",
        "message" => "Erfolgreich eingeloggt!",
        "data" => $result
    );
}
$con->close();

echo json_encode($response);?>
```

EDIT 1:

As soon as I use `dataType: 'json'` I receive nothing (not even the string), so I continue using 'text'. Does my PHP file need a change to receive JSON?

Here are the things I tried the comments:

`console.log(typeof d);` returns string

`alert(JSON.stringify(d));` returns `"{\"status\":\"f\",\"message\":\"Benutzername und Passwort stimmen nicht ueberein\"}"`

`alert(JSON.parse(d));` returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0`

Any more recommendations? Thank you!

Comment: This `dataType: "text",` should be `dataType: "JSON",`

Comment: If `JSON.parse(data)` does not work and `JSON.stringify(data)` returns the data with additional slashes then this indicates that you might have some characters (e.g. Invisible ones) that might make the json invalid. What error do you get for `console.dir(JSON.parse(data))`, how does the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` look like?

Comment: try moving $con->close(); before echo and try console.log(typeof d);

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/weltenbummler/Weltenbummler1/Weltenbummler1/app/login.php?username=' + name + '&password=' + pass,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    success: function (e) {
        alert( JSON.parse(e.message) ); // undefined
    }
});
```

Comment: For the data shown in the question `e.message` is a text and not JSON, why should the OP try to parse that? If the retruned data is correctly recognized as JSON then `e` would alread hold the parsed object.

Comment: if datatype is text, he could just do "alert(e)", op said, its json, so he/she needs to parse in order to transform the return data unto a proper javascript objects.

Comment: Yes but the OP says that `alert(d);` shows the JSON string, and `alert(d.message);`  shows `undefined`. So if `dataType: 'json'` would correct the problem that the returned data is not parsed by jQuery, then `JSON.parse(e.message)` would try to parse the `"Benutzername und Passwort stimmen nicht ueberein"` which is not JSON. If it would not solve the problem, the `d.message` would still be `undefined` and `JSON.parse(e.message)` would show an error because of parsing `undefined`.

Comment: sadly this did not work...as soon as I change the dataType to "json" I recieve nothing, not even the string anymore.

with "text" i get the string but the alert of '( JSON.parse(e.message) );' //nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You can read out the exact recieved data with chrome developer:
1. I recieved a string with hidden variables: #$63434;{"status":false,...}
and with 2. With PHP errors aswell

To 1.: 
PHP buffering variables fireing your code --> scope it with `ob_start();` and `ob_end_clean();` 
reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9985307/8036245

To 2.: Just fix your php code: I had the issue, that not defined variables alert missing reference

After that I could even fire the $.getJSON(..) call!
Hope this will help somone :)

Answer (score -1):

- `contentType` is the header sent to the server, specifying a particular format.
  Example: I'm sending json or XML
- `dataType` is you telling jQuery what kind of response to expect.
  Expecting JSON, or XML, or HTML, etc....the default it for jQuery to try and figure it out.

The [$.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) has full descriptions of these as well.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/weltenbummler/Weltenbummler1/Weltenbummler1/app/login.php?username=" + name + "&password=" + pass,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (d) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(d.message))
    },
});
```

Comment: For the data shown in the question `d.message` is a text and not JSON, why should the OP try to parse that? If the retruned data is correctly recognized as JSON then `d` would alread hold the parsed object.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo json_encode($response, true);
```