# Ajax fails but status code is still 200 "OK"

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm not sure why this is happening but i have a simple Ajax Code:

```
$.ajax({ url: "/javascript/testing.js"})
    .done(function(data){ console.log(data) })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         console.log(jqXHR);
    });
```

`.fail()` get's executed the status code is "OK". Also the data is present in `responceText` to the actual legit data. Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: what is `responsceText`?

Comment: @karthikr legit data, `javascript` in my case. Error is `parseerror`

Comment: @Jessica Can you examine the request in the browser to see if there is any additional information?

Comment: What does `testing.js` return?

Comment: Set your dataType, it might be trying to parse it as "script"

Comment: Returns javascript, @nullability I attemted to try "application/script" it don't work.

Comment: Do you hava ajaxSetup globally somewhere?  If so, make sure that you don't have some default set that would cause a conflict with this code, e.g. `method` set to `post`.

Comment: @user1167442 the only thing i have is `$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});`

Comment: What is the parseError?

Comment: Did you try `$.getScript`?

Comment: @user1167442 `Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.` I don't want to execute it.

Comment: Also, based on your example -> How can you tell `fail` is getting executed.  They should return the same thing.

Comment: What do you want to do with it?  In other words, are you extending another object, saving it as a global function | global variable?

Comment: @AlexMcp Its just 'parseerror'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to parse the javascript file, then the dataType should be `script`:

```
$.ajax({ url: "/javascript/testing.js", dataType: "script" })
.done(function(data){ console.log(data) })
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     console.log(jqXHR);
});
```

If you are still getting a `parserError` then there is a problem with your `testing.js` file.

If you don't want to parse it and just retrieve it, then the dataType should be `text`:

```
$.ajax({ url: "/javascript/testing.js", dataType: "text" })
```

Comment: testing.js is just a regular javascript file. I replace the content to just `test` and it's still not working.

Comment: just `test` is not valid javascript. If you want to retrieve it without parsing it as javascript, set the dataType to `text`. I've updated my answer to reflect this.