# jQuery SVG map - pulling content as JSON from jQuery Ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, svg, mapsvg

Below is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "content/content.json",
    success: function( data ) {
        check = true;
        ajaxMap = data;
        drawMap(data);
    }
});

function drawMap( data ) {
   $('#map').mapSvg({
      source: 'maps/test.svg',
      colors: {
         selected: "#00431e",
         disabled: "#ffffff"
      },

      tooltipsMode: 'custom', 
      zoom: true,
      zoomButtons: {'show': true, 'location': 'left'},
      pan: true,
      responsive: true,
      zoomLimit: [0,500],

      marks: data,  // here I pass data from JSON file

      tooltipsMode: 'custom',
      zoom: true,
      pan: true,
      responsive: 0,
      zoomLimit: [0,100]
  });
}
```

It works when I pass data as JSON format directly in marks, but when I pass data variable it doesn't work.

**Updated:**
This my json data:

```
[
  { c: [50.84199288,122.83167],
      attrs: {'src': 'markers/pin-yellow.png'},
      tooltip: '<h2>Dublin - Ireland</h2><p>Embassies and High Commissions</p><a href="http://www.dfat.gov.au/geo/ireland/" title="http://www.dfat.gov.au/geo/ireland/">Read More</a>'
  },
  { c: [44.94199288,119.93167],
      attrs: {'src': 'markers/pin-yellow.png'},
      tooltip: '<h2>London - United Kingdom</h2><p>Embassies and High Commissions</p><a href="http://www.dfat.gov.au/geo/united_kingdom/" title="http://www.dfat.gov.au/geo/united_kingdom/">Read More</a>'
  },
  { c: [28.94199288,100.93167],
      attrs: {'src': 'markers/pin-yellow.png'},
      tooltip: '<h2>Header</h2><p>Embassies and High Commissions</p><a href="#" title="">Read More</a>'
  },
  { c: [44.94199288,115.93167],
      attrs: {'src': 'markers/pin-yellow.png'},
      tooltip: '<h2>Header</h2><p>Embassies and High Commissions</p><a href="#" title="">Read More</a>'
  },
  { c: [20.94199288,135.93167],
      attrs: {'src': 'markers/pin-yellow.png'},
      tooltip: '<h2>Header</h2><p>Embassies and High Commissions</p><a href="#" title="">Read More</a>'
  }
]
```

Comment: The question isn't clear (at least to me). Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you call `drawMap()`?  Like this, we don't know what `data` looks like. You should also use the developer tools to examine what gets passed to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define dataType property if you aspect response in json format. currently you are getting data as string.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "content/content.json",
    dataType:'json',
    success: function( data ) {
        check = true;
        ajaxMap = data;
        drawMap(data);
    }
});
```

or use `data=JSON.parse(data)` in your success handler.

Moreover what you have shown in example is object literal , not an json. see http://json.org/ . JSON.parse() will give error on your example.

Answer (score 3):

Valid JSON is valid JavaScript but valid JavaScript is not necessarily valid JSON. The json data you posted in the question is not valid JSON; you can verify this using the [JSONlint](http://jsonlint.com/) service. `jQuery.ajax` will raise an error when it expects JSON but encounters invalid JSON ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186770/ajax-request-return-200-ok-but-error-event-is-fired-instead-of-success/)). To fix the issue, you must revise the server side code to emit valid JSON. To begin with, the keys need to be enclosed in double quotes.