# JQuery .get() to retrieve JSON response - success callback not triggering

Tags: jquery, httphandler, ashx, jquery-callback

I'm doing the following - it's a JQuery .get() that calls an http handler that should return a JSON object.  In the callback function for the .get() (i.e. the third argument passed in the .get() function), which is called when a successful http response is received, the Latitude and Longitude properties of that object are then assigned to a couple of other properties

```
    var url = "/handlers/GeolocationByIpAddress.ashx";
    $.get(url, {}, function (data) {
        g.currentLat = data.Latitude;
        g.currentLng = data.Longitude;
    });
```

When I set a breakpoint on the line:

```
        g.currentLat = data.Latitude;
```

It isn't hit, which suggests that the success callback isn't triggering.  I've checked the request to the .ashx handler in the 'NET' tab of Firebug, and it's showing a successful JSON response with a correctly formed JSON object, with the 'Latitude' and 'Longitude' properties correctly set.  I've tried organising the above code a different way so that the callback calls another function and passes the 'data' to it, instead of self-invoking.  The separate function is never called, which seems to confirm that the .get() just isn't recognising a successful response.  Why would that happen when I can see the successful response in the 'NET' tab of Firebug?

Comment: console.log(data) check what you get

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186770/ajax-request-return-200-ok-but-error-event-is-fired-instead-of-success related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using '$.getJSON()' instead?

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    g.currentLat = data.Latitude;
    g.currentLng = data.Longitude;
});
```

Have you tested if it fires an error? Try listening to '.fail();

It seems like '$.get()' should be capable of handling JSON automatically, maybe try telling it your receiving JSON. (Your response headers might be wrong)

```
$.get(url, {}, function (data) {
    g.currentLat = data.Latitude;
    g.currentLng = data.Longitude;
}, "json");
```

Comment: Sadly I can't comment on other answers yet, but I want to help...

John Munsch: Are you sure it's malformed, or do you have any idea what format that is? I'm quite surprised it actually created an object formatted like that.

Chris Halcrow: What browser are you debugging with? And how did your JSON look in Firebug?

Comment: Hi there.  Thanks loads for the response.  I'm using Firebug on Firefox, and when I output the JSON to the Firebug console, it's formatted like this -  Object { RegionCode="G2", CountryId=29, CountryName="New Zealand", more...} - the Latitude and Longitude are there

Comment: Brilliant thanks, now working using the code you suggested :)

Answer (score 2):

Add `JSON` as fourth parameter to the `.get()` function like:

```
$.get( "test.php", {}, function( data ) {
    console.log(data);// Check webconsole what you get in data        
}, "json" );
```

Comment: Thanks Kishor, I still get the same result, although the following is now logged in the console: Object { RegionCode="G2", CountryId=29, CountryName="New Zealand", more...} - the Latitude and Longitude are there, which looks correct to me...

Comment: Can you access lat and long now?

Comment: Hi Kishor.  Thanks, although no, unfortunately this didn't work.  Upvote for the suggestion though :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll bet I know! Dump "data" to the console with "console.log(data)" as the first line within your callback function. Likely what you see there will have your returned data buried within a wrapper object. For example, you may have to look at data.data.Latitude or something similar to get down to the data which was sent from the function on the server.

Comment: Thanks John, I've tried this and the following is logged: Object { RegionCode="G2", CountryId=29, CountryName="New Zealand", more...} - the Latitude and Longitude are there, which looks correct to me...

Comment: If it truly looked like that, it doesn't look correct to me. I've seen a similar problem with Java before where we weren't getting a real JSON object back to the client. In JSON it would have looked like { "RegionCode" : "G2", "CountryId" : 29, "CountryName" : "NewZealand"... }

Comment: Thanks John.  I don't think it's malformed though, I think that Firebug on Firefox just formats the JSON like that in the console.  Any other ideas?