# How do I return an empty JSON object for methods of return type void?

Tags: serialization, servicestack, void, servicestack-text, servicestack-bsd

### Requirement:

I am looking for a way to return an empty JSON object (such as `{}`) when the return type of my ServiceStack service method is `void`.

### Reasoning:

The reason for wanting to return an empty JSON object for `void` types is due to the way jQuery handles content type `application/json`. As [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186770/ajax-request-return-200-ok-but-error-event-is-fired-instead-of-success) jQuery will throw an error when a `200 - OK` status is received with no content. Which is what is currently returned for void.

### Foreseen issues:

I am hoping there is an easy way to serialise `void` to `{}`.

- If this is possible, would there be adverse consequences for doing this?
- Would it affect the ServiceStack c# client when it expects `void`?

Comment: void methods don't return anything. period. you need to instead change your return type. I mean, how are you calling it in the first place and how is it returning data?

Comment: I agree with @Ahmedilyas. What prevents you from changing the method into something which returns an object? Just return ``null`` at the end and you should be set.

Comment: Hmm you guys are right, but I was hoping that ServiceStack would be smart to see the content type is `application/json` so it must return something (not empty data), so in place of `void` send an empty object. I'll just have to make an empty object to send, it feels somewhat 'hacky'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the simple solution was to override the `OnAfterExecute` method in my custom ServiceStack `ServiceRunner`.

If there is no response (because the method returned `void`) and the `ContentType` is `application/json` then send an empty object.

```cs
public override object OnAfterExecute(IRequestContext requestContext, object response)
{
    if(response == null && requestContext.ContentType == "application/json")
        response = new {};

    return base.OnAfterExecute(requestContext, response);
}
```