# getJSON request fails

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json file with some data to append into a div in the html document when a button is clicked:

html:

```
<div class="json"></div>
<button id="one"></button>
```

here the javascript:

```
function one(){
    $("#one").click(function(){
        $.getJSON('one.json',function(data){
            alert("success");       
        })
        .done(function() { alert('getJSON request succeeded!'); })
        .fail(function() { alert('getJSON request failed! '); })
        .always(function() { alert('getJSON request ended!'); });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   one();
});
```

the one.json file is in the same directory of js file. When I click the button the alert is 
"getJSON request failed"...where is the mistake?

Comment: Is the html file also in the same directory? Try to make a root-relative call like "/folder/one.json" instead

Comment: what is the path to the html & js file? are they in different directories

Comment: This is impossible to answer, could be anything! Wrong filename, wrong path, not running a webserver, something else entirely

Comment: or malformed JSON: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186770/ajax-request-return-200-ok-but-error-event-is-fired-instead-of-success/6186905#6186905

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if below code works :-

```
 $.getJSON('/YourDirectory/one.json',function(data){
            alert("success");       
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

`$.getJSON()` takes a url as the parameter for where to get the JSON, not a file path.

`$.getJSON('/one.json', function (data) { ... });`

or

`$.getJSON('http://localhost:1234/one.json', function (data) { ... });`

Take the url for the `one.json` file and paste into a browser address bar. If the browser returns the JSON content, then you know you can use that url in the $.getJSON()` call.

Answer (score 1):

If you html is opening from url

```
localhost:80/project/test.html
```

then the json path will be

```
localhost:80/project/one.json
```

So make sure html and json in same folder.

Answer (score 1):

well, either remove the success callback inside the getJSON method , and use `.done` `.fail`.. or use success callback only

```
 function one(){
   $("#one").click(function(){
    $.getJSON('path/to/one.json')
    .done(function() { alert('getJSON request succeeded!'); })
    .fail(function() { alert('getJSON request failed! '); })
    .always(function() { alert('getJSON request ended!'); });
   });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  one();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Ajax request will look in the url of your current page, so if you are in :

- `mysite.com/index.html`, it will look on `mysite.com/one.json`

and

- `mysite.com/category/index.html`, it will look on
  `mysite.com/category/one.json`

If you have a modern browser, you can open the developer console to see what is the exact request made.