# Ajax Webmethod not being called

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I make a total of four Ajax calls in my .NET application. Three of them work without a hitch except the last one.

**Note: I HAVE to use .aspx for these calls and not mypage.aspx/mymethod because of our architectural constraints.**

Ajax call that **works**:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myaddress/GenerateOpinionHTML.aspx",
    data: JSON.stringify({ id: featureId, pageNumber: pageNumberIndex }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        SOME PROCESSING (IT WORKS)
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        var err = xhr.responseText;
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

and

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GenerateOpinionHTML(int id, int pageNumber)
{
    // ...
}
```

Ajax call that **does not work**:

```
console.log("SUBMITOPINIONCLICK");
var param = " ";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myaddress/SaveOpinion.aspx",
    data: JSON.stringify({ parameter: param}),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log("SAVE OPINION SUCCESSFUL");
        console.log(msg.d);
        CloseLB('GiveOpinionLB');
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        var err = xhr.responseText;
        console.log("ERROR " + "STATUS: " + status);
    }
});
```

and

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SaveOpinion(string parameter)
{
    // ...
}
```

The web method `SaveOpinion` is never called according to the logs. Do you have any ideas or suggestions? I tried adding parameters, without parameters, checking my web.config file (though I shouldn't have since the other calls work)...

The error I get on the **browser** console is a "parseerror". I'm certain I wouldn't be getting an error if the method was called.

Comment: Can you track the network reqest in developer tools and check if any error is coming

Comment: Id this is not something new, the web method url format should be [urltoPage].aspx/[methodname] not methodname.aspx.

Comment: why do you set url like `url: "myaddress/SaveOpinion.aspx"` please change to this one and try `url: "myaddress/SaveOpinion",` without aspx extension

Comment: A bit off topic, but don't stringify your JSON. Just keep it as an object, its whole purpose and power is to be an object whose properties can be accessed. By stringifying it, you waste CPU time, you lose that power, and you have to de-stringify it server-side, that's just counterproductive.

Comment: Is the `console.log("SUBMITOPINIONCLICK")` ever called?

Comment: The console.log IS called. I cannot track the request directly with developer tools. @OnurTOPAL I know how it should be, but we have a specific architecture and this is how we call the methods.

Comment: @JeremyThille Thanks for the suggestion I hadn't thought about that!!

Comment: try just this one `data: parameter,`

Comment: @MirzaDanishBaig you mean `param` right? since  "parameter" is the variable name in the code (string parameter).

Comment: @Joze yes try to pass

Comment: @MirzaDanishBaig nope that's not it.

Comment: you have check that to directly call the url in browser? it is working?

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint at webmethod and test. Also use crome's rest console extension to test if its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so we ***"solved"*** it. We just found a very dirty band-aid workaround that works.

We made a custom handler (.ashx) that we defined in our architecture as a *SaveOpinion.aspx* page.

We then called this custom handler page with jQuery and voilà it works, we had to obviously pass all necessary parameters manually, ie. fetching all values from textBoxes etc with jQuery and not from the context as we did before.

Since this is run in some sort of thread (I don't really know the details) we had to configure it so that it simulates the same user authentification.

Anyway I hope this provides some measure of guidance for those with this kind of obscure problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think your URL should be like

```
url: "Your FolderName/PageName/Function Name",
```

Like

```
url: "myaddress/SaveOpinion.aspx/SaveOpinion"
```

but in your code this is different so that please check.

Comment: Please read the whole question. I specifically said that our architecture does not work like that. We HAVE to use .aspx since it is a redirection call. The other calls work except this one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if method `SaveOption` return something to the client? 
[If you specify dataType as json, you should return (at least): {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186770/ajax-request-return-200-ok-but-error-event-is-fired-instead-of-success)