# Ajax, error:function is always getting called , and the status shown in firefox is 200

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am using jquery with `ajax()` . I am adding data to my `table`, so data are getting SUCCESSFULLY added but i am unable to get the response from the `URL` i have specified . The problem is error:function is always getting called , but i am getting status code = 200 in my browser , and my `json` data is also getting added in the database and  success:function() <-- is never getting called

```js
$("#add_detail").on('click',function(){
               //alert("cd");
            $.ajax({
               type:'POST',
                url:'http://www.------',
                dataType: "json",
                data:{
                    gym_name:$gym_name.val(),
                    plan_type:$plan_type.val(),
                    duration:$duration.val(),
                    amount:$amount.val()
                },
                async:false,
                success:function(){
                    alert("Success");
                }
                ,
                error:function(data, msg){
                    alert(msg);
                }

            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="add_detail">Click here</button>
```

Comment: Take a look to this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186770/ajax-request-return-200-ok-but-error-event-is-fired-instead-of-success

I hope helps!

Comment: @Nilesh Thakkar -> alert(msg) is printing --> error

Comment: This is the response from the url {
    "success": "true",
    "message": "ok"
}

Comment: @jcarrera , thanx for replying , but i didnt get any help