# .NET (ApiController) / jQuery .ajax : what to return from POST?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

In a Post method within a Controller derived from ApiController what should I return to indicate success to jQuery ?

I've tried HttpResponseMessage but jQuery sees this as an error (even though the argument the jQuery error handler clearly has a 200 status).

The jQuery looks like this :

```
processParticipantEvent: function(parID, evtType, evtNotes, successFunction, errorFunction){
    debugger;
    var requestURL = '/api/participantevent';
    var json = {"parId" : parID, "evtType": evtType, "evtNotes": evtNotes};
    var jsonArray=JSON.stringify(json);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: requestURL,
        data: jsonArray ,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) { successFunction(data); },
        error: function (data) { errorFunction(data); }
    });
},
```

I've read this : [Ajax request returns 200 OK, but an error event is fired instead of success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186770/ajax-request-return-200-ok-but-error-event-is-fired-instead-of-success) which seems like it's touching on the same issue but I suspect it's out of data as it won't work for me ?

Just to be clear all I want to do is to return a plain old 2xx with no data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @Beyers the return with OK() just works.

I've created the same structure here and worked.

My Controller has this:

```
[Route("api/participantevent")]
public IHttpActionResult Test()
{
    return Ok("");
}
```

And at client I've changed your function just to simplify:

```
processParticipantEvent= function(){
    debugger;
    var requestURL = '/api/participantevent';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: requestURL,
        data: [{'test': '1'}] ,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) { alert('success'); },
        error: function (data) { alert('error'); }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks - what was good about this answer was it gave me the return type (IHTTPActionResult) as well as the mechanism for using it.

Answer (score 5):

As per the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript
>   object. Cross-domain "json" requests are converted to "jsonp" unless
>   the request includes jsonp: false in its request options. The JSON
>   data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and
>   a parse error is thrown. **As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also
>   rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead.**

So if you want to use jQuery ajax you have to return a valid json string, just use the following in your API controller:

`return Ok(new {});`

Note this is a jQuery ajax "feature", using Angular for example to do an ajax post I can use `return Ok();` inside my controller and everything works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for this response, I appreciate it. I marked the @Luiz response as correct due to it providing me with a little more information but yours covered similar ground, thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is with the `requestURL`.  Its value is absolute and `http://api/participantevent` does not exist.  Try using a relative value.

```
var requestURL = './api/participantevent';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I appreciate it. In fact the URL does resolve OK because the code within the controller is actually executing in response to the .ajax call - it's just that once that has completed jquery takes the response I was sending it (a HTTPRresponseMessage) as being an error and so fires the error handler. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you get an OK response, It is probably not a valid JSON.
I would recommend to you to check the HTTP response in the browser and try to run the JSON.parse function with the responseText and see whether it fails.

Comment: You can also post here the responseText if you need javascript help

Answer (score 0):

1. I usually declare a class like below:

   public class AjaxResult
   {

   ```
   private bool success = true;
   private List<string> messages;

   public bool Success { get { return success; } set { success = value; } }
   public List<string> Messages { get { return messages; } }

   public AjaxResult()
   {
       messages = new List<string>();
   }
   ```

   }
2. In the controller, the action(to which the ajax request is made) should have JsonResult as return type.

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public JsonResult Action(string id)
   {
       AjaxResult result = new AjaxResult();
       //Set the properties of result here...
       result.Success = true;
       result.messages.Add("Success");
       return Json(result);
   }
   ```

3.And your ajax call will look like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: /ControllerName/Action,
        data: { id: "Test"},
        success: function (data) { alert('success'); },
        error: function (data) { alert('error'); }
   });
```