# jQuery.ajax() for JSONP returns 200, but a parse error runs the error callback instead of the success callback

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

First all of all, I know there are similar posts in the website, but none of them has solved my problem.

I want to get JSON file from a web server.  The JSON file was checked by JSONLint, so the syntax is verified to be OK.  The JSON data is retrieved from a URL similar to this: www.examplewebsite.com/data.json

My jQuery Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({

    url:url",
    dataType:"jsonp",
    contentType: "application/json",
    type:"get",
    success:function(){
        console.log("OK");
    },
    error:function(data,status,error){
        console.log(data " "status+" "+error);
    }
});
```

This is the error:

> :parsererror Error: jQuery222030055767520832166_1465026956736 was not called

What I have done so far:

- Added callback function (jsonpCallback: fname) (I really want to know that if we have to add callback function for reaching server side JSON?) the function fname works (`alert("OK");`), but I still get errors.  One of the error messages was "undefined was not called"
- Added jsonp:false option
- Changed dataType:jsonp to json but got `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error
- Double check if the resulting JSON is valid

**UPDATE1**

My json content (used for testing):

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "first_name": "Sara"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "first_name": "Lois"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "first_name": "Annie"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "first_name": "Gregory"
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "first_name": "Fred"
}, {
  "id": 6,
  "first_name": "Antonio"
}, {
  "id": 7,
  "first_name": "Denise"
}, {
  "id": 8,
  "first_name": "Susan"
}, {
  "id": 9,
  "first_name": "Jeffrey"
}, {
  "id": 10,
  "first_name": "Jean"
}]
```

**UPDATE2**
According to @Michael 's explanations, I updated headers and ajax code, dataType:"json" but I got Access-Control-Allow-Origin error. My header check results for json file:

```html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK => 
Date => Sun, 05 Jun 2016 00:21:59 GMT
Server => Apache
Last-Modified => Sat, 04 Jun 2016 22:27:58 GMT
Accept-Ranges => bytes
Content-Length => 440
Access-Control-Allow-Origin => *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers => origin, x-requested-with, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods => PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Keep-Alive => timeout=10, max=200
Content-Type => application/json
Connection => close
```

Any ideas? PS: Also, I tried to write another method (IfModule) still got problem.

Comment: Have you tried removing the data type all together?

Comment: Can you show the actual JSONP data returned from the server?  There are syntax differences between JSON and JSONP, so it's important to see the actual data that's generating the parse error.

Comment: Ya, JSON is not JSONp

Comment: @Julian I've already tried it, I got Access-Control-Allow-Origin error, I added my json file as well.

Comment: "It is worth noting that an empty response is also considered invalid JSON; you could return {} or null for example which validate as JSON." I found this quote on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186770/ajax-request-return-200-ok-but-error-event-is-fired-instead-of-success?rq=1. Is it possible the server is serving an empty response, even though it's resulting in a 200?

Comment: Maybe try replacing the JSON with `{}` and making sure your Ajax call is receiving the data correctly.

Comment: That is not `jsonp` so error is triggered. Why are you requesting `jsonp`? Does API support it? Not all API's do. If not use a proxy

Comment: @Julian I had read the that topic before I opened this topic, I changed couple of json file they are validated by JSONlint results are same. @ charlietfl I am trying to reach a json file in a server with Ajax that's why I am using jsonp otherwise I got Access-Control-Allow-Origin error. I don't have adequate information about API's. Is there a way to test about support?

Answer (score 5):

The data that you're trying to retrieve is JSON, not JSONP.  Requesting JSON from another domain via Ajax will result in an `Access Control Allow Origin` error, as you found.  Ajax will allow JSONP to be retrieved from a different domain, but the content *must* actually be JSONP, or you receive a parsing error, as you found.

So, what can you do?  If you control the server that the JSON data is being requested from, you can handle requests from your domain via the response headers.  You only need to set these headers:

- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *your server*
- Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
- Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
- Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Once you have that, you can simply do a JSON (not JSONP) Ajax call, and you'd be set.

If you cannot rely on CORS for some reason, and you *do* control the remote server, simply return the data as JSONP instead of JSON.

However, if you don't control the remote server or can't use CORS for some reason, things get weird pretty quickly.  The answer for [How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6169703/6263819) gives a good explanation of how to make this work with iframes and `window.postMessage`.  Granted, that example is for a POST, but all of the information holds up if you're just trying to GET from a remote server.

It's *very* difficult to give a precise answer in this case, because there's no information at all about whether you control the remote server, nor what language/tech stack your own server is using.  There is excellent coverage of various solutions in the article [4 jQuery Cross-Domain AJAX Request methods](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2013/09/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-request.html), and one of them might solve your issue (make sure to note the *disadvantages* of each before deciding on one).

If you're still at an impasse at this point, you should consider using your own server as a proxy, so that the Ajax call can be made to your server, and then your server can make the cross-domain call to the remote server to retrieve the data.  This will result in a longer response time, but will get you *exactly* what you need, with full control over each aspect of the process.  It's typically only a few lines of code to do this, but it does need to be done on the server.

Consider this Ruby on Rails proxy example:

```
def json_proxy
  Net::HTTP.start("www.examplewebsite.com") do |http|
    render json: http.get("/data.json")
  end
end
```

Your server language and/or tech stack may be different, but that's the gist of it.  You can embellish and add new features if you wish, including being able to use a single proxy for all requests, by passing the request details to the proxy.  You can perform validations, replacements, and even merge multiple responses together using a proxy like this.  It can be a powerful tool in your toolbelt.

For more information on CORS, see the [W3C Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) spec for the details on how CORS works.  You should also look at the fine coverage in [html5rocks.com Using CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/), as this covers quite a lot of the fundamentals of how CORS works and what you can do in a CORS environment.