# javascript not show results on success

Tags: javascript

I have this JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".deleteImage").on('click', function() {
          var idmess = $(this).data("id");
          var token = $(this).data("token");
          $.ajax({
              url: '{{ url('admin/deletemulti') }}/'+encodeURI(idmess),
              type: 'DELETE',
              dataType: "JSON",
              data: {
                  "id": idmess,
                  "_method": 'DELETE',
                  "_token": token,
              },
              success:function() {
                alert("it Work");
              }
          });
      });
  });
</script>
```

is working just fine (data is removing from my DB and I get `200` in network), except **I cannot get my `alert`** any idea why is that?

## UPDATE

[my network](https://image.ibb.co/nMbvNn/547.gif)

[my network response](https://image.ibb.co/eoZAoS/78.jpg)

`Delete Function`

```
function destroy(Request $request) {
    $image = Image::find($request->id);
    Storage::delete($image->name);
    $image->delete();
  }
```

Comment: how do you know it is working fine?

Comment: @brk because data is removing from my database

Comment: please check network tab from developers tool

Comment: @brk I get `200` in network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try passing an argument in your success function.

```
success:function(data) {
   alert("it Work");
}
```

Comment: can you show what are u getting in response in network section?

Comment: why is your response empty ? send something from backend

Comment: I shared my delete function, how i send something?

Comment: return response()->json(['deleted' => $image], 200);

Answer (score 1):

You have used ajax with dataType : json
So you need to respond with a **valid JSON as HttpResponse** else it gets into a error event.

The response of your api call:

```
{{ url('admin/deletemulti') }}/'+encodeURI(idmess)
```

should be a valid JSON. Please check api response value and fix it, or share it so that we can help you update that.

In case the response is not a valid JSON, success function will never get triggered and hence alert is not getting executed.

**More info :**

[Ajax request returns 200 OK, but an error event is fired instead of success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186770/ajax-request-returns-200-ok-but-an-error-event-is-fired-instead-of-success)

Comment: now what more info do you need? so i can share for you?

Answer (score 0):

When I'm making backend for myown use, and when I'm writing json, I usually put my json on success like session = true, or something like that, so later you can check like :

```js
success: function(json) {
 if(json.session == true) {
   alert('something')
 }
}
```

Maybe it's not the best solution, but it's working perfectly for me.