# Ajax response is fine but in error method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm facing a problem in ajax call. When I have called to given URL, Everything is fine but it is coming in error method of ajax response, 
Code is below

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "My_URL",
    Method: "Get",
    async: false,
    success: function(msg){ 
        console.log("success");
        console.log(msg);
    },
    error: function(msg){
        console.log("error");
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
```

Please see the attached image which is fine but response in error method. Why ?

[image: Image of response]

Any can guide me please ?

Comment: your ajax syntax looks horrible ,try using formatted ajax syntax

Comment: First of all, don't use ``async: false`` property because it's freeze the window while request is processing.

Comment: I think your browser's defaults to dataType json, but the string `OK` is not a valid json. Check this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186770/ajax-request-returns-200-ok-but-an-error-event-is-fired-instead-of-success

Comment: Refer to this : https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: Problem is, Everything is fine why it error method. I have gone through jquery page  as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax request returns 200 OK, but an error event is fired instead of success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186770/ajax-request-returns-200-ok-but-an-error-event-is-fired-instead-of-success)

Comment: I have gone through that question but not found any thing for my issue