# How to use POST fetched data in another django view ERROR 200

Tags: django, ajax, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to use data that was fetched using an AjaxQuery, parse that data and send the user to another view to do other stuff. However, I'm getting a Error 200 and a snippet of my test view and I have no idea why!
The main idea of what I want to do is get the user location using a js function, then I use an AjaxQuery to get the coordinates, use POST in a view whose function is to handle the data and then send the user to another view where I can use those coordiantes to do other stuff.

**AjaxQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(sol) {
    $("#send-my-url-to-django-button").click(function(sol) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/establishments/process_url_from_client/",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                lat: sol[0],
                lon: sol[1],
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                },
            success : function(json) {
                alert("Successfully sent the URL to Django");

            },
            error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
                alert("Could not send URL to Django. Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**View.py**

```
def get_coordinates_view(request):
return render(request, 'base2.html')

def process_url_from_client(request):
res = request.POST.get('data')
return render(request, "results.html")
```

**Urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path("", views.get_coordinates_view),
path("process_url_from_client/", views.process_url_from_client),]
```

The results.html for now is just an html with hello, the error I get with this is: Could not send URL to django. Error 200: hello!

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message is misleading you. There's no error sending the request to Django. However, there *is* an error in understanding the response.

You've told jQuery to expect a JSON response, by specifying `dataType: "json"` in the `$.ajax` call. But your Django view is not returning JSON, it is (for some reason) rendering an HTML template. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186770/ajax-request-returns-200-ok-but-an-error-event-is-fired-instead-of-success) demonstrates, when jQuery cannot parse a response according to the dataType it fires the error handler

Either drop that `dataType`, or preferably actually return JSON:

```
return JsonResponse({'message': 'ok'})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your solution was really simple yet I was struggling with this