# Ajax, Django: status 200 but throws error instead of success

Tags: django, ajax, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to post comment with ajax, but it is not working. When I press button console is not printing any error (like 404 etc.), comment is not being posted.
Object returned by error:

> {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ,
> setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …} abort: ƒ (e) always: ƒ ()
> catch: ƒ (e) done: ƒ () fail: ƒ () getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()
> getResponseHeader: ƒ (e) overrideMimeType: ƒ (e) pipe: ƒ () progress:
> ƒ () promise: ƒ (e) readyState: 4 responseText: "↵" setRequestHeader:
> ƒ (e,t) state: ƒ () status: 200 statusCode: ƒ (e) statusText: "OK"
> then: ƒ (t,n,r)
> **proto**: Object

In command line I see:

> "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 5572

When I change button to "submit" it is posting and responding with proper JSON like:

> {"comment": {"id": 16, "author": 1, "content": "test", "post": 12}}

My code is below, any help is appreciated:

views.py

```
def homepage(request):
    profiles = Follow.objects.filter(follow_by=request.user.profile).values_list('follow_to', flat=True)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(author_id__in=profiles).order_by('-date_of_create')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pk = request.POST.get('pk')
            post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
            new_comment = Comment.objects.create(
                author = request.user.profile,
                post = post,
                content = form.cleaned_data['content']
            )
            return JsonResponse({'comment': model_to_dict(new_comment)}, status=200)
    form = CommentForm()
    context = {
        'posts': posts,
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/homepage.html', context=context)
```

template

```
<div class="comments" id="{{ post.pk }}" style="display: none">
            {% include 'posts/comments.html' %}
            <form action="" method="post" class="commentForm" data-url="{% url 'post_comments' post.pk %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="hidden" name="pk" value="{{ post.pk }}">
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button type="button" class="commentBtn" id="{{ post.pk }}">Comment</button>
            </form>
```

addComment.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.commentBtn').click(function () {
        let serializedData = $('.commentForm').serialize();
        let btn = $(this);
        let id = btn.attr('id');
        console.log($(".commentForm").data('url'));
        $.ajax({
            url: $(".commentForm").data('url'),
            data: serializedData,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $(`#${id}.comments`).load('/posts/comments/' + data.post);
                $('textarea').val('');
            },
            error: function(textStatus) {
                console.log(textStatus)
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Edit:
I used this question: [Ajax request returns 200 OK, but an error event is fired instead of success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186770/ajax-request-returns-200-ok-but-an-error-event-is-fired-instead-of-success?rq=1)
, deleted `dataType: 'json'` and added `contentType: 'application/json'`
and now I got 403 error.

Comment: Hi,  you miss `.` near `$("commentForm").data('url')..` .

Comment: Hi, thanks but it does not help.

Comment: Also , do one thing `$('.commentForm').serialize()` print this and see what its giving .As i can see  in your code there are mutliple post and every post will have comment section ..so this will be sending data from all form with class `commentForm` .Instead change it like `$(this).closest(".commentForm").serialize()` so this will get data only from form where button has been clicked .

Comment: And that was the problem. Thanks a lot. Post it as answer to get extra bounty ;). PS: how to make form not disappear after posting comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have use `$('.commentForm')` to send data of form to backend it will get all forms with class `commentForm` and send data of all forms that's the reason its not working .Instead you can change this `$('.commentForm').serialize()` to  `$(this).closest(".commentForm").serialize()`.

Also , you are using `#${id}.comments` inside success function of ajax this will override any content inside `#${id}.comments` and load new content from url i.e : `/posts/comments/..` .So , to avoid this one way would be surround your `{% include 'posts/comments.html' %}` with some outer div and then change your selector i.e : `#${id}.comments > .yourouterdivclassname` so new content will be loaded inside that `div` only thus form will not get removed .